# What should my path variable contain?

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables

My computer has successfully managed to overwrite the %Path% variable and wipe itself out.
I've replaced it with:
C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
but my file browser doesn't work properly and I can't open up the advanced system variables dialog through control panel.
The computer doesn't have any system restores to try and get the old path.
I need to get this working so I can reinstall nodejs for work. At the moment when I try to add to it it breaks things.
What am I missing from my Path?

Comment: Where you've got C:\Windows\, My PATH variables contain %SystemRoot%\ , but that should be the same thing. Those three items should be the required items. Don't forget to reboot after changing those vars.

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I didn't think of this. I was so focused on replacing the PATH I didn't think. Put this as a reply and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you've got C:\Windows\, My PATH variables contain %SystemRoot%\ , but that should be the same thing.
Those three items should be the required items.

Don't forget to reboot after changing those vars.

Comment: There's no need to reboot after changing environment variables. Explorer will pick up the changes and any process started from Explorer afterwards will have them. Other processes that are already running of course usually don't notice. If you want to be sure, then you can re-logon, but a re *start* should never be necessary. We're not talking about `autoexec.bat` here anymore.